# should NOT have additional properties

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor, openapi-generator

I am new to Open API specification ( ia m using 3.0). I am playing with swagger Editor online tool and I am getting a weird error of:

**"should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: Data1, Data2"**

Here is  sample of YAML file I am working with:

```
paths:
 /api/assignment:
    post:
      tags:
      - Assignment
      summary: "Endpoint to create Resources in  system"
      description: "This endpoint will create blah blah"
      operationId: CreateResource
 parameters:
    - name: assignment
      in: body
      description: "This is an  object to be sent"
      required: true
      schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              Ganesh:
                type: integer
              Test:
                type: string
              RefClaim:
                Data1:
                  FirstName:
                    type: string
                  LastName:
                    type: string
                Data2:
                  FirstName2:
                    type: string
                  LastName2:
                    type: string
```

I have seen all questions asked and tried with those but I could not get answer. 
*Note: I am using Open Api specification 3.0.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1) `in: body` parameters are an OpenAPI 2.0 thing. OpenAPI 3.0 uses [`requestBody`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) instead.

2) [Nested objects](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#nested) also need the `type: object` and `properties` keywords.

The correct version is:

```yaml
paths:
 /api/assignment:
    post:
      tags:
      - Assignment
      summary: "Endpoint to create Resources in  system"
      description: "This endpoint will create blah blah"
      operationId: CreateResource
      requestBody:   # <-----------
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                Ganesh:
                  type: integer
                Test:
                  type: string
                RefClaim:
                  type: object      # <-----------
                  properties:       # <-----------
                    Data1:
                      type: object  # <-----------
                      properties:   # <-----------
                        FirstName:
                          type: string
                        LastName:
                          type: string
                    Data2:
                      type: object  # <-----------
                      properties:   # <-----------
                        FirstName2:
                          type: string
                        LastName2:
                          type: string
```